# Fantasy novel in which people develop a tattoo-like design that signifies their power

Tags: story-identification, novel

About five or so years ago I read a book that was fantasy and whose title I can't remember for the life of me. It was set in a world where by the age of 16 or 18, a tattoo-type thing appeared on the back of your neck and that was your power. The main character, whose name I can't remember, lived on the streets and wanted to get out of the city she lived in because it was a terrible place if you weren't rich. She met this guy in the sewer who had the power to control animals, and they decided to run away with these rich twins. It was illegal for them to do so, but they still escaped and they were trying to get to this magical city. And in the second book I think she developed the shadow power.
If you know the book please comment and if you want more info please ask for it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please add anything and everything else you can recall to the question; the more details you provide the more likely someone will recognize it.